# Auto Format DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, font-size

I have a dynamic set of data and a static layout for a DataGridView that will be used to display information on TVs.

This DataGridView is the sole Control on my form. I utilize AutoResize to Fill the entire screen.

However if I do not manually modify the text size it either all doesn't fit or there is excessive empty space.

How can I dynamically or automatically scale the Font so all the data fits on the screen?

Comment: Can you please post your GridView code sample?

Comment: I don't have a sample to post. I have no idea how to dynamically or automatically modify the font to best fit the data in the box. I don't see how the code I use to populate the GridView would be of any help?